# Rewriting the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlperformance

I have a table with the following sample data. The table actually contains more than 10 million rows.

| tableid | Id | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | su1 |
| 2 | 2 | su1 |
| 3 | 2 | su2 |
| 4 | 3 | su3 |
| 5 | 4 | su1 |

I have to get a count of all the ids that only have type su1. If the id has su1 but also another type then it should not be counted. This is the query I came up with.

```
Select Count(*) From (
Select id
From table t
Where exists (select null from table t1 where t.id = t1.id and t1.type = 'su1')
Group by id
Having Count(*) = 1) a
```

tableid is the primary key. Id has a non-clustered index on it. Are there any other ways of writing this query?

Comment: What is your motivation for finding another way?

Comment: This query was taking too long to run.

Comment: Ar, well that is quite a different question. You need to add that information to your question. And, as for all performance related questions, you need to include your execution plan (using Paste The Plan).

Comment: (And can you clarify if you just want the count, or if you want all the columns returned for all the matching rows?)

Comment: Can a given ID value have multiple rows with the same value (su1) for type? Do you KNOW this and is it enforced with constraints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why you have `Having Count(*) = 1` as it doesn't seem to be reflected in the requirements.

But this query is much better written as follows

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT id
    FROM [table] t
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN t1.type <> 'su1' THEN 1 END) = 0
) t;
```

And for that, you would need the following index

```
[table] (id) INCLUDE (type)
```

Answer (score 1):

Given this table and sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.[table]
(
  tableid int, 
  Id      int, 
  type    char(3), 
  INDEX   IX_table CLUSTERED (Id, type)
);

INSERT dbo.[table](tableid, Id, type) VALUES
(1, 1,  'su1'),
(2, 2,  'su1'),
(3, 2,  'su2'),
(4, 3,  'su3'),
(5, 4,  'su1');
```

One way would be:

```
;WITH agg AS
(
  SELECT tableid, Id, type, 
    mint = MIN(Type) OVER (PARTITION BY Id),
    maxt = MAX(Type) OVER (PARTITION BY Id)
  FROM dbo.[table]
)
SELECT tableid, Id, type 
  FROM agg 
  WHERE mint = maxt AND mint = 'su1';
```

If your clustered index is on `Id, type` this will allow for a single clustered index scan:

[image]

Though it is a little messy with some spools that we might not want. How about David's suggestion (assuming you're on SQL Server 2017 or better):

```
SELECT tableid = MIN(tableid), Id
  FROM dbo.[table]
  GROUP BY Id 
  HAVING STRING_AGG(type, ',') = 'su1';
```

Oh yeah, that's much better:

[image]

- Examples on [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5ca61704a37a9adb6b458752f71e7a9a)

Comment: do you want to try the profiler on my query as well (I don't have access to SQL Server on this computer). I think the results should be much different since no analytic functions involved (may even be faster with a join instead of a subselect?)

Comment: @David542 your solution [has to scan the table twice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QH9nJ.png), which _might_ be better than the spools, but hard to know against 5 rows and how their data skews.

Comment: I see, how do you think doing [`array_agg`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/functions/aggregate/array-agg`) would do and checking the result = ['su1'] ?

Comment: @David542 Sorry, I have absolutely no idea what `array_agg` does or what U-SQL even is.

Comment: oh sorry, that was from azure data lake docs, not sql server.

Comment: though I suppose `string_agg` on 2017+ might work .

Comment: @David542 ooh, yeah, interesting thought, but it does assume 2017+.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something but can't you do a `COUNT DISTINCT` after filtering out everything except the items with `type='su1'`. In that case we'd just have:

```
WITH tbl (tableid, id, type) AS (
    select * from values (1,1,'su1'), (2,2,'su1'), (3,2,'su2'), (4,3,'su3'), (5,4,'su1')
)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM tbl
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tbl WHERE type != 'su1')
-- 2
```

Here is the SQL Fiddle, I removed the `COUNT DISTINCT` so you can see the individual results and it's easier to check [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d3a46c8b4732e6ced26a5e6a1973b300).